# Need help Improving Basic C# Calculator

Tags: c#, code-cleanup

I made this Basic C# Calculator to reflect on what I've learned these past few days. I'm an absolute beginner and I wanted to get suggestions on improving and shortening it.

I've tried to add switch statements and multiple methods, but it has been really hard grasping them.

```
using System;

namespace lol
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi! What is your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(name + " What do you wanna do?");

        Console.WriteLine("Type \"+\" for addition");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"-\" for Subraction");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"*\" for Multiplication");
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"/\" for division");

        string operation = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Now, Give me number one: ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Now give me number two: ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (operation == "+")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
        }
        else if (operation == "-")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
        }

        else if (operation == "*")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);

        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think a calculator needs to know your name.

Comment: you can use switch instead of if , else other thing looks ok

Comment: Could you show those "switch statements" and "methods" that you tried and tell about the issues you are having with them?

Comment: @FalcoGer yeah, but I was just trying to add as must stuff as possible inside this. To be honest I think got a little too excited writing a proper first program.

Comment: instead of string compare, you could use enums for the operation

Comment: you could do input checking.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, unfortunately, I didn't save them. As soon as I finished the code I replaced it with Switch, and it did not work for some reason so I changed them back to "if". Next time I'll be careful to Note them down, sorry!

Comment: @FalcoGer Could you explain it?

Comment: A suggested extension: try what happens when you input "aa" instead of a number, or "0" for the second number and a "$" for the operation - then prevent those errors from crashing your app

Comment: Right now, an invalid input (say, writing "hello" instead of a number) will crash your program. It'd be better to print out something like "'hello' is not a number, please try again." instead of crashing :)

Comment: @Luann I did try to do that, but I was having trouble figuring out how to do it. I'm sorry for sounding so dumb, but could you tell me how I can add that? Thank you!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks for Suggesting!

Comment: This question doesn't belong on this site as it is Opinion Based. However, feel free to ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is made for exactly this kind of question.

Comment: Why do they all say “addition”?

Comment: @MartinVerjansthank you for that. I'm completely new around here so I didn't know that. I'd take my future questions similar to this over there. Thanks!

Comment: Using ifs are ok, there is just a little bit performance between ifs and switch case. Especially, it doesn't matter which you use in small or medium projects even huge.. Your code ok.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I am so sorry I didn't notice that Mistake earlier. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

If it better for your eyes, you can write like that:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi! What is your name?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(name + " What do you wanna do?");
        string[] operations = new string[] { "\"+\" for addition", "\"-\" for subtraction", "\"*\" for multiplication", "\"/\" for divsion" };
        foreach (string operation in operations) { Console.WriteLine("Type " + operation); }

        string cmd = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Now, Give me number one: ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Now give me number two: ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (cmd)
        {
            case "+": Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2); break;
            case "-": Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2); break;
            case "*": Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2); break;
            case "/": Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly does help! I'm still a beginner, so I'd have to Understand some things you did in there. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using enums and checking if the user input is valid. I also added a loop that checks if the user wants to input equations.
References:

- [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)
- [Switch Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

You can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aIwX5P

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    enum eOperator
    {
        opAdd = 0,
        opSub = 1,
        opDiv = 2,
        opMul = 3,
        opInvalid = int.MinValue + 1,
        opQuit = int.MinValue
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
        eOperator op = eOperator.opQuit;
        string input = String.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 'quit' at any time to exit.");
        // repeat until the user wants to quit.
        do // while(op != eOperator.opQuit)
        {
            Console.Write("a = ");
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
            if (double.TryParse(input, out a))
            {
                // input is a valid double and was stored in a
                Console.Write("Operator: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case "+":
                        op = eOperator.opAdd;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        op = eOperator.opSub;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        op = eOperator.opMul;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        op = eOperator.opDiv;
                        break;
                    case "quit":
                        op = eOperator.opQuit;
                        break;
                    default:
                        op = eOperator.opInvalid; // can't be left as quit
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. +, -, *, / or quit for operator.");
                        break;
                }
                if (op != eOperator.opQuit && op != eOperator.opInvalid)
                {
                    // user didn't choose to quit or type something invalid
                    Console.Write("b = ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
                    if (double.TryParse(input, out b))
                    {
                        // input is a valid double and was parsed into b
                        double result = a; // we use the operator on a, so we might as well just store a into the result right away.
                        // do the operation on result.
                        switch (op)
                        {
                            case eOperator.opAdd:
                                result += b;
                                break;
                            case eOperator.opSub:
                                result -= b;
                                break;
                            case eOperator.opMul:
                                result *= b;
                                break;
                            case eOperator.opDiv:
                                // Div by 0 check. without this, this still works since double has +/- inf values.
                                if (b != 0.0) // comparing double with = and != is usually bad idea, but 0.0 is saved without rounding errors.
                                {
                                    result /= b;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Div by 0");
                                    op = eOperator.opInvalid;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                // this if branch checked for the other two operators. since we never chanced op after that check, this exception should never happen.
                                // it is still a good idea to include it to find errors in your logic, should they have occurred.
                                throw new Exception("This shouldn't happen.");
                        }
                        if (op != eOperator.opInvalid)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString());
                        }
                        // the only invalid operation is div by 0 for now. the message was sent to the user in that case, so no else is needed at this point.
                        // alternatively you can store an error message into a string, and when op = opInvalid, then display that error message here centralized.
                        // this would be a good idea if multiple things can go wrong.
                    }
                    else if (input == "quit")
                    {
                        // input for b was an invalid number, but input was 'quit'
                        op = eOperator.opQuit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // input for b was an invalid number and also not 'quit', display error message
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Type a number or Quit");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (input == "quit")
            {
                // input for a was invalid number, but 'quit'
                op = eOperator.opQuit;
            }
            else
            {
                // input for a was invalid number and also not 'quit'
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Type a number or Quit");
            }
        // repeat until the user wants to quit.
        }while(op != eOperator.opQuit);
        Console.WriteLine("Bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll Look into it and search for those topics.

Comment: I'll say this though. It looks Really advanced.

Comment: if you want advanced you could try equation parsing :P

Comment: @AhmadDaPenguinz i included some links to msdn for enums, select case statements and input checking with tryparse.